# excel set id for each category using vba

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have on excel file with so many rows. It file contains Product Id Column and Product name column like bellow

[image]

I want to add product ID to these products by name using vba(something like cluster). the result should be like this:

[image]

note that my original excel file is the first picture

Comment: And what about selecting both A and B columns and sorting them?

Comment: Maybe enter in `A2`: `=SUM(A1,B2<>B1)` and fill down

Comment: @PLB Can you explain more? Note that i want to repeat the id

Comment: @DavidPeterson Select both columns, then find button `Sort & Filter` and choose your desired sorting type.

Comment: note that my original excel file is the first picture. i don't have product ID inserted and i asked this question because my file has 38000 rows

Comment: Do you have the product id somewhere else? Or do you need to make up a new product id for the A column? You can use an excel formula (VLOOKUP) to find data in another sheet or in another workbook.

Comment: @OlleSjögren i don't have. i want to make new id based on each category. and if product id mathch the product name, repeat it in A column

Comment: if you can assume that Product name is sorted then in A2 out the value 1 and in A3 =IF(B2=B3, A2, A2 + 1) and drag down.

Comment: @Dan Your solution is simple and effective, you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @OlleSjögren out of interest, did my formula not work for you?

Comment: @lori_m Yes it did, sorry I missed it. I had to replace ',' with ';' to make it work, bud I did that for the solution Dan had too. Maybe different regional settings? Yours was as simple and as effective and should be posted as a separate answer too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that Product name is sorted then in A2 put the value `1` and in A3 `=IF(B2=B3, A2, A2 + 1)` and drag down.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you want to use VBA? This can be done relatively simply using a reference table and vlookup.

Create a table in the workbook that will list the product name and the corresponding product ID.

```
    Product Name    Product ID
        x              1
        y              2
        j              3
```

Next, enter a VLOOKUP formula into cell A2

```
    =VLOOKUP(B2, $G$1:$H$5, 2, 0)
```

Replace $G$1:$H$ with the location of the reference table you just created. This will find the product name in the table and return the corresponding ID. You can then copy the formula down the 38000 rows.

Comment: This would work if there was somewhere you could look up the values, but as I understand it the question is how to make up the product id for the different products.

Comment: Ok, if that's the intention I would still create a reference table and then populate the Product ID with sequential numbers - assuming that's suitable for his product IDs.